# Is Mjolnir an Action Die?

Tags: dice-masters

Here is the card text for Mjolnir "Thor's Hammer":

> Deal 4 damage to all characters other than Thor (yours and your opponent's). * Deal 5 damage instead.

If so, Storm "Weather Witch" would also be immune to Mjolnir's damage, which is a useful player advantage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Mjolnir is an Action Die.

There are only two types of dice in Marvel Dice Masters - character dice and action dice.

> Actions ... have no numbers around the die's custom symbol.

Mjolnir has no numbers around the hammer icon, thus it is an action die.

Source: [rules](http://dicemasters.com/wp-content/uploads/mdm/MDM_Rules.pdf).